# Put text on one line

Tags: html, css

I want to put the "nav" text onto one line. It is currently displayed in a column.

```
<div class="nav">
  <p>Home</p>
  <p>City</p>
  <p>Nature</p>
  <p> Gallery</p>
  <p> Maps</p>
  </div>
```

```
.nav {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 37px;
    color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 365px;
    word-spacing: 90px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most navbar items are placed using `display: flex`. You might also want to separate your items inside the flexbox (here, they are your `p` tags) a little with `gap` applied to `.nav` (or, alternatively with `margin`/`padding` on the `p` tags):

```css
    .nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 16px;
    }
```

I recommend giving the MDN article on [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) a read through to learn more about using it in a layout, as it has many useful properties!

Answer (score 0):

Change the display property of the `P` elements.

```css
    .nav {
    display: inline;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 37px;
    color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    left: 10px;
    word-spacing: 40px;
}

.nav p {
    display: inline; 
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <p>Home</p>
  <p>City</p>
  <p>Nature</p>
  <p>Gallery</p>
  <p>Maps</p>
  </div>
```

but why use `p` to begin with? it's a `display:block` element. maybe `span` or `li`?

Answer (score 0):

Heres some sample of a flex navigation from your code. I edited some of you css so you can easily manage it when it when you resize it. I added some hover on it so it looks like a navigation.

```css
.nav {
    display: flex;
    gap: 20px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat';
    font-weight: 100;
    font-style: normal;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #000000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 48px;
    right: 20px;
    top:10px;
    word-spacing: 90px;
}

.nav p:hover {
    color:green;
    text-decoration:underline;
    }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <p>Home</p>
  <p>City</p>
  <p>Nature</p>
  <p> Gallery</p>
  <p> Maps</p>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `display: flex` and `flex-direction: row` to make your elements display in a row

Comment: Use `column-gap`. Please mark my answer as answered if it solved your problem